# How to flatten only selected layers affected by Addition mode in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I have a layer that uses *Addition* mode since it made the nicest desired effect. When I duplicate it, it makes it even nicer. But when I merge the layers, it looks different as if the *Addition* mode disappears. I would basically want to flatten only those 2 layers to give me that final same effect on top of the other layers. How do I flatten merge only those 2 layers together and still give me the same effect on top of all other layers?

[image]

Comment: Hi.  Can I ask why you want to merge the layers?   What's the purpose?

Comment: I want to keep my layering simple because sometimes I have 3 duplicate layers that create the desired effect but it can get confusing with too many layers and slows down my machine. I guess it is not possible to merge something that has "modes" in them?

Comment: Ok, in that case I  would follow xenoid's advice - put the duplicate layers in a layer group, and set the layer group blending mode to "Pass through".  This is a way to organise your layers without having to merge them.  It's always best to try to avoid merging layers in GIMP if you possibly can, because merging is a destructive operation.

Comment: alright, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The addition mode disappears because the resulting layer is put in `Normal` mode, but if you put the result layer back in `Addition` mode, you recover the previous aspect, as far as I can tell.

Another solution for easy management is to put these layers in a group, and set the group to "Pass-through" mode.

Otherwise, it easy to merge layers but very difficult to unmerge them, so I keep them separate unless I have a very good reason not to (and even then, I'm likely to merge copies, so the layer count still goes up).

Some more explanations:

This is a lot more complicated than it looks because "Addition" isn't really addition under the hood (due to "gamma" considerations), so it is not associative. In a layer stack, operations are done from the bottom(*):

```
A (bottom) + B + C + D (top)
```

is really done as

```
( ( A + B ) + C ) + D
```

so the original question is finding a compositions of  C & D so that:

```
( A + B ) ⊕ (C ⊗ D) = ( ( A + B ) + C ) + D
```

and `⊕` and `⊗` are layer compositions that may, or may not, be "Addition".

If you use the "legacy" blend modes, these work directly on gamma corrected values so it may be easier to find an equivalent composition, but their overall effect won't be the same...

(*) Unless you use layer groups, that act as parentheses and force an order of composition, unless the group itself is in `Pass-through` mode in which case it just a management thing.

Comment: hey thank you for your input! :) just out of curiosity, so it is not possible to flatten 1 layer with an Addition mode on it and get that resulting layer to preserve its look?

Comment: See additional explanation in answer (too long for a comment)